GoogleMapServices: Adding Polygon to the map causes exception in version 19.0.0
I've recently switched from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0 but I'm getting crashes in my app while adding polygons to the googleMap.
With older version it is working fine, but new one throws ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable 
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelWriter.writeTypedList(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:5)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions.writeToParcel(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.addPolygon(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolygon(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:2)

Is there any major change that has occured in PolygonOptions? Because I can't find anything there.
PolygonOptions.writeTypedList is used only for points and stroke pattern.
This is function I'm using to add polygons:
private fun addPolygon(polygonData: Pair<*, PolygonOptions>) {
    googleMap?.addPolygon(polygonData.second)?.let {
        it.tag = polygonData.first
        polygons.add(it)
    }
}

Inside points there is just List<LatLng> with values. But
19.0.0:
[{latitude=32.4016388, longitude=22.6369665}, {latitude=32.2016388, longitude=22.6369665}]

18.0.2:
[lat/lng: (32.4016388,22.6369665), lat/lng: (32.2016388,22.6369665)]

This is main difference I see. Its both for holes list and points list
I've tried to manually create PolygonOptionsAdapter utilizing @FromJson and @ToJson but it is returning some obfuscated names for variables.
Instead of points there is field called zza, then you have zzb, zzc.
I don't think I can manually create adapter to deserialize and serialize this json from com.google.android.gms.maps.model since its decompiled as class file.

I'd suspect, the model class being used for Moshi's ORM is not being properly annotated, because else it should indeed be List<LatLng> or ArrayList<LatLng>... the other option would be making it parcel-able, which is probably not required, when returning the expected data-type with ORM. That * in the signature should be ArrayList<LatLng> ...because with * this fails one call later, when passing an unexpected argument.


is custom entity class. I have TypeConverter for it using moshi.
Pair<*, PolygonOptions> is ParameterizedType used by JsonAdapter.

So this type consists of Pair::class.java, Entity::class.java, PolygonOptions::class.java. Maybe there is problem with that adapter that moshi cant recognize internal structure of PolygonOptions::class.java and convert correctly json to List. But weird  thing is its working for older version of library.
